# trace on direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, trace

Let $\mathcal H_n$ is separable Hilbert space for every $n\in\mathbb N$. By $\mathcal{B(H_n)}$ denote the algebra of all linear bounded operators acting on $\mathcal H_n$. As we know there is canonical trace $\tau_n$ on each $\mathcal{B(H_n)}$. Further we know that every $\mathcal{B(H_n)}$ can be considered as subspace of the direct sum $\bigoplus\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{B(H_n)}$. Is there trace $\tau$ on the direct sum $\bigoplus\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{B(H_n)}$ such that $\tau(A)=\tau_n(A)$ when $A\in \mathcal{B(H_n)}$? In other words can one from traces $\tau_n$ on $\mathcal{B(H_n)}$ construct a trace $\tau$ on the direct sum $\bigoplus\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{B(H_n)}$ such that  $\tau |_{\mathcal{B(H_n)}} = \tau_n$?

Comment: Have you tried defining $\tau$ by $\tau(A_1,A_2,\ldots)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tau_n(A_n)$?

Comment: There is no tracial state (canonical or otherwise) on $\mathcal B(\mathcal H_n)$ unless $\mathcal H_n$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @s.harp If $H$ is infinite-dimensional, one can define a trace $\tau:B(H)_+\to[0,\infty]$ on the positive elements of $B(H)$.